# Getting http post form data in Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, http

Hey I am trying to send the post request using express and node and here is my code.

index.html

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="/form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" name="imagename"></input>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></input>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

My app.js file is given below:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
   extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/form', function(req, res){
 res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
 setTimeout(function(){
     res.send(JSON.stringify({
        imagename: req.body.imagename || null

    }));
  }, 1000);
});
```

Now I should get the output as imagename: //value added in the form if true or else null. And I am always getting a null value. I tried to log the value of req.body.imagename and I am getting undefined instead of the value that I inserted in the form. Any help would be appretiated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to add the `body-parser` to your Express's app.

```
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

However, I've seen that you've declared your form with the `enctype='multipart/formdata'`. This is usually used to make file uploads, if it's really what you want, you're going to need to use [another parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) for it.

Comment: I am trying to add a file and so I have used multipart/formdata. and I have included the  two lines for bodyparser, just forgot to copy here. But because nothing was working I thought that first lets make the text working and then I will look into file and commented the file upload part. Thanks.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski and Edmundo Rodrigues Thanks a lot for your feedback. I was able to send the data when I removed the multipart from the form. Now I will try and use mulder and hope that works with the files. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You required `'body-parser'` middleware, but forgot to use it in your `express` app.

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded())
```

and you don't need this one

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Comment: I already had the app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded()) in my code just forgot to copy here. and I need the second part because I will be using file uploads in the future.